# ! Package pdftex.def Error: File

Tags: pdftex, gif

I got this error, when I tried to insert a .gif figure

! Package pdftex.def Error: File `CEOC 400/Figures/CEOC400030-gif-converted-to.

and I tried to use

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}

\epstopdfDeclareGraphicsRule{.gif}{png}{.png}{convert gif:#1 png:\OutputFile}
\AppendGraphicsExtensions{.gif}
```

in the preamble but it didn't work

Comment: it is much simpler to convert the gif to png in advance and then include the png file

Comment: I can reproduce the issue if I run `pdflatex` *without* the `-shell-escape` option, which is needed to call `convert`.

Comment: I have a problem with this option $-shell-escape$ I can't enable, and I tried all the solutions proposed but it is not working. I need for several documents